# Inserting markers and info windows (Google Maps) from a database using PHP and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-maps

My objective is to obtain data from a table in a database and show it on the map. My table has three columns: LATITUD (stores the latitude)(type=float(10,6)), LONGITUD (stores the longitude)(type=float 10,6) and  ASUNTO(stores the information)(type=VARCHAR). The first two have information of the location of the marker, while the third column stores information related to the marker. The content of this last column is the one I want to show with an info window.

To achieve this inside the body element of the page i have decided to insert a script element (javascript) which I use to create the map and to load all the information related to it.

Inside this javascript code I have included PHP code which is in charge of making a query to the database to obtain the content of the table we mentioned at the beggining in an associative array. Inside this code through a while loop I want to load all the markers with their corresponding info windows.

Loading the markers didn't gave me any problem, to load them I used this while loop code.

```
while ($row = $resultado->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC )) {
              echo '  var myLatlng1 = new google.maps.LatLng('.
              $row['LATITUD'].', '.$row['LONGITUD'].'); 
              var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({ 
              position: myLatlng1, 
              map: map, 
              });';
 }
```

Inside the PHP script I inserted this code and works fine to me. I have the problem when I want to add info windows for each marker which contain the information stored in the "ASUNTO" column mentioned at the beggining. When I modify the code shown above to add info windows I have problems. The code that is giving me problems is the one below.

```
while ($row = $resultado->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC )) {
              echo ' var asunto = '. $row['ASUNTO'] . ';';
              echo '  var myLatlng1 = new google.maps.LatLng('.
              $row['LATITUD'].', '.$row['LONGITUD'].'); 
              var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({ 
              position: myLatlng1, 
              map: map, 
              });



              var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: asunto
              });


              infowindow.open(map, marker1);


              ';
        }
```

I think that the code line that is giving me problems is the first one inside the loop, which I will show now below.

```
echo ' var asunto = '. $row['ASUNTO'] . ';';
```

The reason I believe this, is because the "infowindow" variable when I change its content to a string which is not obtained through PHP and is directly inserted doesn't gives me any problem and displays an info window when it is called using the "open"method. The next code below doesn't gives me any problem.

```
while ($row = $resultado->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC )) {

              echo '  var myLatlng1 = new google.maps.LatLng('.
              $row['LATITUD'].', '.$row['LONGITUD'].'); 
              var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({ 
              position: myLatlng1, 
              map: map, 
              });



              var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: "hello"
              });


              infowindow.open(map, marker1);


              ';
        }
```

As you can see the content of the infowindow have changed and when I changed it, it worked correctly and the map was able to load. I would like to show info windows which display the information stored in the database rather than the string "hello" of the example above.

I would like to know why my approach is failing and how to resolve the problem in order to be able to show the info windows I want for each marker.

Comment: Debugged it? Does it work with variables in general ? Is the variable added correctly? Is it set, before the marker is added ? ...

Comment: With other variables that aren't obtained through php (like a simple string) it works correctly. If it doesn't work i think that i am probably failing with the syntax in the line I mentioned later that I think is the origin of the problem. The marker is added at first and then the info window is added.

Comment: messing around with '", php and js is hell.Look into the browsers console ( pure js) to check for mistakss

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the database, nor the php.  The problem is where you echo that data.

One simple example, it's quite obvious that this won't work

```
while ($row = $resultado->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC )) {
  echo '  var myLatlng1 = new google.maps.LatLng('.
  ...
```

The while-loop creates multiple instances of this code.  The variable myLatlng1 will simply be overwritten.

What you need to do, is separate the data from the functions.

So you generate 1 var.

It should be something like this (my php is a bit rusty, I hope I'm not generating errors):

```
<?php
$data = array();  // we make an empty object/array, we will fill it with the data in the rows
while ($row = $resultado->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC )) {
  $data[] = array(
    'LATITUD'   => $row['LATITUD'],
    'LONGITUD'  => $row['LONGITUD'],
    'ASUNTO' => $row['ASUNTO'],
  );
}
// now we echo this variable, 1 variable containing all the data
$data_string = json_encode($data);  // this turns php arrays into a javascript-readable object
echo 'var my_data = ' . $data_string .';';  // notice which ; is for javascript and which is for php
?>
```

var my_data will be something like this (I'll insert some locations in Brussels):

```
var my_data = [{"LATITUD":"50.89496405015655","LONGITUD":"4.341537103056892","ASUNTO":"Atomium"},{"LATITUD":"50.84501941894387","LONGITUD":"4.349947169423087","ASUNTO":"Manneken Pis"},{"LATITUD":"50.83847065124941","LONGITUD":"4.376028969883903","ASUNTO":"European Parliament"}];
```

---

Now the javascript.  How do you use infowindows?  I'll use my_data hard coded, so you can copy/paste this code and test the javascript.

don't forget your API key

```
<style>
  html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  #map {
    height: 90%;
  }
</style>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
  var my_data = [{"LATITUD":"50.89496405015655","LONGITUD":"4.341537103056892","ASUNTO":"Atomium"},{"LATITUD":"50.84501941894387","LONGITUD":"4.349947169423087","ASUNTO":"Manneken Pis"},{"LATITUD":"50.83847065124941","LONGITUD":"4.376028969883903","ASUNTO":"European Parliament"}];

  var map;
  function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: 50.869754630095834, lng: 4.353812903165801},
      zoom: 12
    });
    for(var i=0; i<my_data.length; i++) {
      // marker
      var position = {lat: Number(my_data[i].LATITUD), lng: Number(my_data[i].LONGITUD)};
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        title: my_data[i].ASUNTO,
        map: map
      });

      // infowindow
      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: my_data[i].ASUNTO,
        map: map,
        position: position
      });
    }
  }
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```